# Allow user to change luks password

Tags: luks, gnome-disk-utility

Disk Utility allow to change hard disk encryption password with a simple GUI.

I would like to allow non-admin/non-root user to change their luks password (IT have another slot for recovery).

Unfortunately, when trying to change the luks password as non-admin, Disk Utility prompts the user for an admin password to "unlock the encrypted device".

Is there a way to allow this operation? Maybe by adding the user to a specific security group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a polkit rule.

- I created the group `luks-unlock`. This group will be allowed to unlock and change the passphrase of an encrypted filesystem in the polkit rule.
- I created the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/luks-unlock.pkla`:

```
[Change LUKS Password]
Identity=unix-group:luks-unlock
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-change-passphrase;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-change-passphrase-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-lock-others;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-crypttab;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-other-seat;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system
ResultActive=yes
```

- Add the allowed users to the `luks-unlock` group.

Work fine on Ubuntu 22.04.